SSL handshake failed Error code 525 nginx proxy manager docker
I have a docker compose running nginx proxy manager and a dozzle image for testing.
version: '3.8'

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
  my_proxy:
    name: my_proxy
    external: true
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.90.0/24

services:
  nginx:
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '80:80' # Public HTTP Port
      - '443:443' # Public HTTPS Port
      - '81:81' # Admin Web Port
    volumes:
      - ./docker/appdata/nginx/data:/data
      - ./docker/appdata/nginx/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./docker/appdata/nginx/config:/config
    networks:
      my_proxy:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.90.23
    environment:
      DB_SQLITE_FILE: "/config/database.sqlite"
      DISABLE_IPV6: 'true'

  dozzle:
    container_name: dozzle
    image: amir20/dozzle:latest
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      my_proxy:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.90.25
    ports:
      - 8888:8080
    restart: unless-stopped

These containers run fine and I can access dozzle through localhost:8888. I have logged into nginx and created my proxy hosts with these settings

(the ssl cert is filled in)

On cloudflare I have these records

And I created an api token with these settings

and I created an SSL on nginx with a DNS challenge and pasted in that token

I have my SSL encryption mode set to Full. When I try to browse to dozzle.mydomain.com I get an SSL handshake failed Error code 525.
Thanks for any suggestions!
Thanks for any suggestions!
